# How is the Fully Connected Layer of a cnn network trained?

Tags: machine-learning, python, cnn

When training a cnn network, only the filters are updated, but how are the Fully Connected Layer weights updated?

Answer (score 1):

Their weights are also trained as well as the weights of the CNN filters.

So, the gradient of the loss is computed with respect to these weights also, and at each gradient step, both of the dense (fully connected) and CNN layers' weights are updated.